# How to define (string+int+...) URL Pattern RegEx Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

my url : 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/avatar/Z0FBQUFBQlhuZWI3ejVzTU10TUwyY0twMFJqZHM5MU1LajdEVnJfSzVWN3RXcUFya00wZjdLOUZmbjBzUG5ZSldibkNXeEtMQ1dsZnE4WXlRd0lNLXllRXhNbS1CUWdFSnc9PQ==`

url pattern : `url(r'^avatar/(?P<avaID>\w+)$', ReportsController.UserImage),`

"w+" this means just string or "d+" this means just digit  but
i need in url with all character in url pattern django how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then match every character using `.`:

```
 url(r'^avatar/(?P<avaID>.+)$', ReportsController.UserImage)
```